# SQL データが存在する場合にのみFlagを立てる

Tags: sql

二つのテーブルがあり、一つを商品のマスターテーブル、もう一つは広告を設定した場合にのみデータが蓄積されるテーブルがあります。

マスターテーブルの各商品毎に広告を設定されているもののみにFlagを立てたいのですが、
なぜかうまくいきません。どのようなSQLコードをかけばよろしいでしょうか。

```
master_table as master
productID,name
45473xc, nintendo
33333xc, sony

ads_table as ads
productID, adsID
45473xc, 32311
```

adsIDは必ず数字になります。
上記テーブルがあり、下記のようにコードを書いたところ

```
with ads as
(
select 
productID,
case
 when adsID >= 1 then 1
 else 0 ends as ads_flag
from ads_table
)

select
master.productID, master.name, ads.ads_flag
from master_table as master
left join ads
on ads.productID = master.productID

where master.productID in
(
45473xc,
33333xc
)
```

なぜか45473xcのレコードしか表示されず、33333xcは表示されませんでした。

```
master.productID, master.name, ads.ads_flag
45473xc, nintendo, 1
```

実現したい結果はこちらです。

```
master.productID, master.name, ads.ads_flag
45473xc, nintendo, 1
33333xc, sony, 0
```

この問題を解決するにはどのようなコードを書けば良いでしょうか。

Comment: そのSQLは正しく実行できていますか？caseのendがendsになっていますし、productID は文字列だと思われますが inのリテラルに’囲みがありませんが。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。これは私の転記ミスなのですが、ご指摘いただいた部分本番コードでは問題なく記載できております。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

試してないですが、こんな感じでどうですかね。

```sql
SELECT master_table.productID, 
       master_table.name, 
       CASE WHEN ads_table.adsID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS ads_flag
  FROM master_table
  LEFT JOIN ads_table
    ON master_table.productID = ads_table.productID
```

Comment: ありがとうございました。ご提案いただいた内容をwith句に反映したところ、うまくいきました。